# EF Code first - Lazy Loading How to set up and access the joining table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool IsInStock { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public List<ProductOption> ProductOptions { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

}

public class ProductOption
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductOptionName { get; set; }
    public string ProductOptionDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Now I know when your using Code First EF, so that the tables are created correctly. You need to do something like this.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(p => p.ProductOptions).WithMany().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapLeftKey("ProductId").MapRightKey("ProductOptionId").ToTable("SelectedProductOptionsInOrderedItem");
        });
```

So....

1. Does this mean that if I do something like Product.ProductOptions I will be able to access all associated productoptions.
2. Is this the best way to set it up, or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

To enable lazy load and EF can create derived proxy types  for your collection, that property should be declared this way:

```
public virtual ICollection<ProductOptions> ProductOptions { get; set; }
```

That should be enought. Other aspect is the mapping approach that you use. You choose fluent api, i prefer mapping by convention, but that is a matter of personal taste anyway.

Ok, Mapping by Conventions:
Is the ability of EF that from the name of entities and their properties along with their types, to map our model with the underlying data without providing any other information. 
for example

```
public class Customer {
    public long CustomerID {get; September;} 
    public string CustomerName {get; September;} 
    public Employee AssignedTo {get; September;} 
}
```

With the previous model EF will map database with a table named Customer with: 
. CustomerID bigint primary key column 
. CustomerName nvarchar column 
. Customer_EmployeeID foreign key to Employee table, with the datatype Corresponding to EmployeeID in that table.

You can read more [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/06/01/conventions-for-code-first.aspx)

Comment: When you say mapping by convention what do you mean exactly...?? Some time I do things I don't understand so what part of it is fluent API?

Comment: I have edited the answer to introduce you with mapping by convention. Hope it help, also it worth to says that EF is not the first ORM with that capability, for example NHibernate, my favorit ORM from all times ;) have this from several years ago.